# Using simple relation One-To-Many RedBean and CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, orm, one-to-many, foreign-key-relationship, redbean

In my new project, I decided that I will use the [RedBean ORM](http://www.redbeanphp.com/) system with [CodeIgniter PHP Framework](http://codeigniter.com/).

How can I get all records from a table with a simple relation? I know that I can use `R::exec` or  `R::getAll` queries, but I want to make sure if there any other solution(s).

**TABLE STRUCTURE:**

**languages**

- id
- title

**categories**

- id
- language_id
- title

The field `language_id` in the table `categories` is related with the `id` field in the table `languages`.

**MY GOAL:**

```
SELECT l.title, c.* 
FROM categories AS c 
LEFT JOIN languages AS l 
    ON (c.language_id = l.id)
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list($language1, $language2, $language3) = R::dispense('language', 3);
$language1->title = "PHP";
$language2->title = "Python";
$language3->title = "Ruby";

list($category1, $category2, $category3) = R::dispense('category', 3);
$category1->title = "CodeIgniter";
$category2->title = "Django";
$category3->title = "Rails";


R::store($language1);R::store($language2);R::store($language3);
R::store($category1);R::store($category2);R::store($category3);


$category1->language = $language1;
$category2->language = $language2;
$category2->language = $language3;


R::store($category1);R::store($category2);R::store($category3);

$categories = $language1->ownCategory;
```